# Angular2, NodeJs: Got an error "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" when run onthe localhost

Tags: node.js, angular

I try to run my Angular 2 app and it's backend app (node.js) both on the localhost and get an error in browser's console:

[image]

There are no errors in the backend app:

[image]

I used this code in the backend app to avoid CORS error:

```
app.use(function * (next) {
    this.response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    this.response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    this.response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    yield * next;
});
```

It seems to me the problem is related to the frontend app (zone.js may be?)

How can I solve this problem?

update: the same error after fixing https -> http
  [image]

Comment: Your app is connecting to localhost port 443 (HTTPS without an explicit port), but your server is running HTTP, on port 3000. So that's two issues that need to be solved. Are you using a middleware in your Express (?) app that may be causing a redirect?

Comment: @robertklep didn't notice that. Well I fixed that, but it did not help - I got the same error with "http" `GET http://localhost/mailboxes net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` - I've added a screenshot above

Comment: The problem is not http or https. HTTP uses a default port of 80 while HTTPS uses a default port of 443. If you are using some other port (3000 in your case) you need to explicitly specify the port number in URL. Like http://localhost:3000/mailboxes.

Comment: @robertklep I got the point! Changed http://localhost to http://localhost:3000 and now it works. Thank you very much!